# LAMP max_connections, sleep processes, locked processes, wait timeout, out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, apache, memory-management, database-connection

I'll try to be brief and still be complete. **Thx in advance** for those spending precious time pointing me to a possible solution.

---

PHP/Mysql application on Ubuntu environment.

Original Issue:

```
Keep getting error 'to_many_connections'.
```

When i check:

```
show processlist;
```

there are alot of sleep processes. So i figured those are the cause of the to_many_connections error, because they block any new incoming connections.

Altering mysql settings:

```
Raise max_connections from 250 to 400;
lower wait_timeout from 60 to 15;
```

Connections seemed to work, but now my apache is memory hogging.
It went from 11G to over 25G just by changing those 2 settings.
I can't imagine 150 extra mysql_connections take up 14G of extra memory?
Nor would i expect the wait_timeout setting being lower to increase the memory usage of apache. It should hold less connections in memory therefor using less memory? I expected process-usage to go up, but not the memory. And certainly not in those huge amounts.

Tried realtering mysql settings:

```
keep max_connections at 400
raise wait_timeout to 30 sec
```

Memory usage went down, for about 5 minutes, but after that it went up again.

**Other notes:**

> i've noticed that there are alot of locked processes for a certain
>   table. (mysql: show processlist;)
>       **update:** table is a MyISSAM table.

I've also changed some database implementations, which are not ideal, some pages use 2 connections to the database, since we are going through a phase of code refactoring.
switching from mysql_query functionality to PDO functionality

> **update:**
>
> new pdo functionality has persistent connections specifically set to false (even though it defaults to false)
>   old mysql functionality doesn't use persistent connections either.
>
> ```
>     public function __construct($dbname, $username, $password) {
>         parent::__construct('mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname . ';', $username, $password, array(
>             PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
>             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
>             PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
>             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8;"
>         ));
>     }
> ```

I'm well aware that making several connections to the database is far from a best practise, but our current application is missing ALOT of design-patterns, everything is still procedural, no mvc, no OOP.
I'm obliged to do these kind of practises because my employer wants results and has, at this moment, no intention of doing a complete rewrite of our application to use design/coding standards which should've been implemented a LOONG time ago.
**Anyhow** i would be surprised if this code would be the actual cause, since it has been running flawless for over a week and we've had massive amounts of visits during that week because of the bargain-period (1 month of huge bargains/deals at our stores).

Any insight into this matter would be much appreciated. As of this point, i've got no clue what the next step might be to solving this.

**update2**
closed as the issue has been found but had nothing to do with the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I feel for you with these big complex problems! I will chip in with a few things to see if you have tried

- re: apache memory - my apache testing I have been doing recently, actually points to lowering the number of MaxClients, under an ab or siege test I actually get better performance in my test environment with ~12 rather than 256. Though this is very much in dev environment rather than production so far
- with regards the locked mysql processes, what table type are you using? MyIsam is more prone to locking problems than InnoDB I believe. Myisam is table locking, where innodb is row iirc
- I noticed you wrote

  new pdo functionality has persistent connections set to false

is the old code using persistent connections? I have never had much luck or use for them

- How much do you cache? Do you have mysql query caching enabled, what about using memcache or a nosql system in between the webserver and mysql?

I know a lot of people would say memcache etc isn't a solution for a slow/crashing app but if it gives you a lot more breathing room why not? Also there is a bit of philosophy to when is a cache not a cache? For instance I use redis.io which stores in memory but also saves to disc, whenever the admin system updates mysql it also updates this "cache" it is persistent in the sense the data survives down time - minimal warming up issues - and is always up to date so no lag. Intellectually it can feel a bit like a cop out to sidestep stuff like that, but redis is 6x faster (out of the box) than we managed to get mysql for the same task in our circumstances...

**update**
I see you are using myisam, so any locking issue could be down to that, iirc an update will lock the entire table for the duration, which can cause queries to stack up, snowball and every to fall over

re: caching layer
Caching can sidestep/postpone the issue because you would be connecting to the database less, I have some pages that don't connect at all! I can literally do a mysqld stop and they still work even though they are technically dynamic

On a related note do you connect to the DB routinely at the top of the page or only when needed?

**update**
Extra comment reminded me of a similar issue I had one time where an xml feed (that ran on page request - couldn't pre-cache due to politics!) from a third party provider would run slow just as other areas of the site would get busy, the slow XML feed would cause a bottle neck tying up apache processes and slow down the server, which meant some people wouldn't wait for their pages to finish but the DB would still try and supply the info to the aborted requests as well as new ones, so it looked at first like a DB issue

Comment: I'm not at all a server expert, but i do know i've setup server caching some time ago. But i don't think this has anything to do with the connections problem? insufficient caching would imply slower page loads. But i'm getting no page loads because i can't connect to database. Also updated original topic to better specify info.

Comment: upvoted for nice info. Though apparently the problem was caused by some code a fellow employee had implemented (which at first quick peak, has nothing to do with database connections). Still need to figure out the actual leak/bug, but at least the cause has been located. Thanks for the time you've taken to read up on my issue!

Comment: You're welcome, though I have to confess to have cheated and pulled that off the top of my head ;)

Comment: added another tid bit that might help someone in similar situations, but would be a heckova coincidence if it helped you too!